# Copy files from a Dropbox folder to a droplet in Digital Ocean

Tags: dropbox, digital-ocean

Dropbox again banned my public folder because we exceed the daily limit. That is very stressing for us. So I'm looking for other options to share our media files with our users.

Our site is hosted in a Digital Ocean droplet: 2 GB Memory / 40 GB Disk / SFO1 - Ubuntu LEMP on 14.04

Our media files are in a folder in our Dropbox Pro  account.

There is some way to cut/copy the files from our Dropbox account and paste it to our Digital Ocean account?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where exactly you want to migrate, but these link should be useful for you (or someone else in the future):

[Dropbox client for Linux](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/dropbox-works-with-digitalocean-droplets) - this is a tutorial on how to use Dropbox client with DigitalOcean and sync files between server and Dropbox.

[Mount DigitalOcean Spaces instance](https://levi.lol/mounting-digitalocean-spaces/) - this tutorial will allow you to mount your DO Spaces storage to your DO Droplet using `s3fs`.

[Configure backups to DigitalOcean Spaces](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-s3cmd-2-x-to-manage-digitalocean-spaces) - this one describes how to configure `s3cmd` to exchange your files between server and Spaces.

You could use info above to e.g. download your entire Dropbox data using Dropbox client, then create Spaces instance. Next you would mount Spaces with `s3fs` and just move data "inside" your Droplet onto the newly mounted fs. Or use another server for download and upload to Spaces with `s3cmd` (if network speed and HDD space is your constraint on primary server). Of course, it might be just enough to download data with Dropbox client and keep it on your server without external Spaces, if your HDD/SSD is big enough.

[This link](https://github.com/a2nt/silverstripe-digitalocean-nginx-backup-scripts) might be useful as well when writing your own scripts, these ones help to automate backup to Dropbox using "on the fly" DO instances. I haven't tried this though.